# Is there a better way to segment a numeric column into uniform sets than Case/When?

Tags: sas

I have a column for dollar-amount that I need to break apart into $1000 segments - so $0-$999, $1,000-$1,999, etc.
I could use Case/When, but there are an awful lot of groups I would have to make.
Is there a more efficient way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use arithmetic.  For example you could convert them to upper limit of the $1,000 range.

```
up_to = 1000*ceil(dollar/1000);
```

Let's make up some example data:

```
data test;
 do dollar=0 to 5000 by 500 ;
   up_to = 1000*ceil(dollar/1000);
   output;
 end;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    dollar    up_to

  1        0         0
  2      500      1000
  3     1000      1000
  4     1500      2000
  5     2000      2000
  6     2500      3000
  7     3000      3000
  8     3500      4000
  9     4000      4000
 10     4500      5000
 11     5000      5000
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.  This is a great use case for user-defined formats.

```
proc format;
  value segment
    0-<1000 = '0-1000'
    1000-<2000 = '1000s'
    2000-<3000 = '2000s'
   ;
quit;
```

If the number is too high to write out, do it with code!

```
data segments;
  retain 
    fmtname 'segment'
    type 'n'       /* numeric format */
    eexcl 'Y'    /* exclude the "end" match, so 0-1000 excluding 1000 itself */
    ;
  do start = 0 to 1e6 by 1000;
    end = start + 1000;
    label = catx('- <',start,end);   * what you want this to show up as;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc format cntlin=segments;
quit;
```

Then you can use `segment = put(dollaramt,segment.);` to assign the value of segment, or just apply the format `format dollaramt segment.;` if you're just using it in `PROC SUMMARY` or somesuch.

Answer (score 1):

And you can combine the two approaches above to generate a User Defined Format that will bin the amounts for you.

1. Create bins to set up a user defined format. One drawback of this method is that it requires you to know the range of data ahead of time.
2. Use a user defined function via PROC FCMP.
3. Use a manual calculation

I illustrate version of the solution for 1 & 3 below. #2 requires PROC FCMP but I think using it a plain data step can be simpler.

```
data thousands_format;
fmtname = 'thousands_fmt';
type = 'N';
do Start = 0 to 10000 by 1000;
    END = Start + 1000 - 1;
    label = catx(" - ", put(start, dollar12.0), put(end, dollar12.0));
    output;
end;
run;

proc format cntlin=thousands_format;
run;

data demo;
do i=100 to 10000 by 50;
     custom_format = put(i, thousands_fmt.);
     manual_format = catx(" - ", put(floor(i/1000)*1000, dollar12.0), put((ceil(i/1000))*1000-1, dollar12.0));
output;
end;
run;
```